# Show field on mouseover and hide again after a time delay

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to implement show Name value when mouseover on Id field in the datatable. So tried below code but didnt worked as expected

```
<template lwc:if={showName}>
   <div>
      <span>{Name}</span>
   </div>
</template>
<template lwc:else>
   <div onmouseover={updateShowName}>
      <span>{Id}</span>
   </div>
</template>
```

Below is the lwc JS code

```
@api Name
@api Id
@api showName

updateShowName(){
  this.showName = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
               this.showName = false;
             }, 3000);
}
```

I want to hide Name value after some time let say 3 second later when we mouse over the Id field in the list of data.
From the code able to show Name but post three second the value is not showing Id, the value is retained as Name.
Tired couple of other ways like onmouseleave or onmouseout, but none were returning the value back to Name.

Not sure where I was going wrong. Please suggest me. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Fred, as I was using setTimeout in the method for three seconds showName is not rerendered back on html that is the reason I was not able to see the Id back on the page post three seconds. Not sure why showName is rerendered back to html even though it reactive property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
setTimeout(function() {
           this.showName = false;
         }, 3000);
```

to

```
setTimeout(() => {
           this.showName = false;
         }, 3000);
```

I don't know the technical terminology, but `this` changes to the function itself when using `function(){}`, but not when using an arrow function

Comment: It worked. Thank you @Nick Cook.

Answer (score 2):

Defining a function with `function` keyword, it has its own `this` as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#no_separate_this)

> Until arrow functions, **every new function defined its own `this` value** (a new object in the case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode function calls, the base object if the function is called as an "object method", etc.). This proved to be less than ideal with an object-oriented style of programming.

That's why your code doesn't work, `this.showName` inside that function doesn't reference to your class property `showName`, and that's why Nick is right: changing to an arrow function will solve the issue.

It can be fixed also calling [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) on your function, since
`bind` method let you define which object should be used as `this` for the new function:

```js
updateShowName(){
    this.showName = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        this.showName = false;
    }.bind(this), 3000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed explaining @RubenDG. Now understood clearly.